# How to evaluate ServerWebExchangeMatcher in async WebFilter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

How can I evaluate a `ServerWebExchangeMatcher` in async context like `WebFilter`?

The below fails because `.block()` cannot be called in async context. But how can I then evaluate the matcher, to continue based on that condition?

```
class MyFilter implements org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerWebExchangeMatcher matcher = ServerWebExchangeMatcher.pathMatchers("/some/path/**");
        
        //block() is forbidden in async context
        if (matcher.matches(exchange).block().isMatch()) {
            //decorate the exchange
            return exchange.filter(new ServerWebExchangeDecorator(exchange) {...}, chain);
        } else {
            //continue normal flow
            return exchange.filter(exchance, chain);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as follows which works, but don't know if that's correct:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    ServerWebExchangeMatcher matcher = ServerWebExchangeMatcher.pathMatchers("/some/path/**");
    
    return matcher.matches(exchange).flatMap(matchResult -> {
        if (!matchResult.isMatch()) return chain.filter(exchange);
        return chain.filter(new ServerWebExchangeDecorator(exchange) {..});
}
```